# Testing promises in Play2 for Scala

Tags: scala, testing, integration-testing, playframework-2.0, promise

I have a Play2 application that needs to call external services. I would like to test that I can connect to these services and get the expected answers.

The problem is that the `WS` API only returns a promise of result. This is nice, as it frees me from explicitly doing the request from an actor. But I do not know how to test it.

Is there a way to either:

- Ask for the promise to block until it is satisfied, or
- schedule asynchronous tests in Play2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can wait for the result of a `Promise` with the `await` method, so my test looks like

```
Service.query.await.get must contain("something")
```